# Find Even Length Strings,Javascript

Tags: javascript

This function will take an array of values, and should return an array of all the even length strings.

Anything that's not a string, or not a string of even length, should not be returned in the array.

If there are no even length strings, it should return an empty array.

\And this is what I could do so far

```
function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {

  const evenString = items.filter(item => {
    item === 'string' && item %2 !== 0 ? item.push() : [ ]
  })
  return evenString
}
```

Comment: `return items.filter(x=>x.length%2==0)`

Comment: Just ignore the ternary operator. Especially as a beginner. Just use a regular `if...else...` (although that `else`). And then have a look at how [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works.

Comment: Use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof): `typeof item === 'string'`

Comment: `console.log(typeof item)` `console.log(item.length %2)` and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.filter` already filters the array, you only need to return `true` or `false`. As for the conditions for that, it's if item is type of string and even length. Just translated to javascript.

```js
var strings = ["hello", "worm", 12, "world"];

function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {

  return items.filter(item => {
    return (typeof item === 'string' && item.length % 2 === 0)
  })

}

console.log(findEvenLengthStrings(strings))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

```
function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {
  const evenString = items.filter(item => typeof item === 'string' && item.length % 2 === 0)
  return evenString
}
```

### Why your code didn't work

#### 1

First of all, you are not returning anything from the function. You have to either use `return` statement or remove `{}`

Bad:

```
const evenString = items.filter(item => {
  item === 'string' && item %2 !== 0 ? item.push() : [ ]
})
```

Good:

```
const evenString = items.filter(item =>
  item === 'string' && item %2 !== 0 ? item.push() : [ ]
)
```

Good:

```
const evenString = items.filter(item => {
  return item === 'string' && item %2 !== 0 ? item.push() : [ ]
})
```

#### 2

`item === 'string` will check if `item` is a string containing `string` instead of checking a type. To check a type use `typeof`

#### 3

Filter expect that you return `true` if you want to have the item or `false` if you want to drop it

This: `item %2 !== 0 ? item.push() : [ ]` doesn't make any sense in this context

Comment: PS: `const evenString` is unnecessary. The function name is descriptive enough. Also *"Good:"*  should be *"Not so good"*

Comment: I had a rule in a few projects: **returning expression is forbidden, always return a variable**. So it depends

Comment: Not in the case where the function name states the lone condition. Otherwise I highly suggest to return a meaningful variable name.  `const isEven = (i) => {const isEven = i%2 === 0; return isEven;}` is pure nonsense IMHO.