# Javascript - Find Even Lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am running into errors attempting to write code for the following challenge:

Find Even Length Strings
This function will take an array of values, and should return an array of all the even length strings.

Anything that's not a string, or not a string of even length, should not be returned in the array.

If there are no even length strings, it should return an empty array.

My code so far:

```
function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {
    let evenArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].length % 2 == 0) {
            evenArr.push(items[i]);
        }
    return evenArr;
    }
    }
```

There are 2 points on which my code fails:

```
should return an empty array if passed no items

  ✕ AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal
```

```
should return the correct values from an assortment passed in

  ✕ AssertionError: expected [ 'hi' ] to deeply equal [ 'hi', 'cool' ]
```

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: PSA: [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Even Length Strings,Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73211651/find-even-length-strings-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Your code fails the second assertion because you are returning `evenArr` the moment you find a string of even length. Your `return` statement must be outside the `for` loop:

```js
function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {
  let evenArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].length % 2 == 0) {
      evenArr.push(items[i]);
    }
  }
  return evenArr;
}

console.log(findEvenLengthStrings(['hi', 'cool']))
```

As for the first assertion, simply add a check for `undefined` on `items`:

```js
function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {
  if(!items) return []
  let evenArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].length % 2 == 0) {
      evenArr.push(items[i]);
    }
  }
  return evenArr;
}

console.log(findEvenLengthStrings())
console.log(findEvenLengthStrings(['hi', 'cool']))
```

Although it's much simpler to implement a solution with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
function findEvenLengthStrings(items) {
  if(!items) return []
  return items.filter(e => typeof e == 'string' && e.length % 2 == 0)
}


console.log(findEvenLengthStrings())
console.log(findEvenLengthStrings(['hi', 'abc', 'cool']))
```